# Subclass PasswordResetConfirmView returned token becomes "set-password"

Tags: django

I tried to Subclass my PasswordResetConfirmView for me to create an error message if token is invalid. After some trial and errors, this is what I have come up with based on this [Github file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py):

```
class MyPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):


    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):


        # I declared these myself since the variable itself is from other class and they only have these strings as value
        INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN = '_password_reset_token'
        # I declared these myself since the variable itself is from other class and they only have these strings as value

        assert 'uidb64' in kwargs and 'token' in kwargs

        self.validlink = False
        self.user = self.get_user(kwargs['uidb64'])

        if self.user is not None:
            token = kwargs['token']
            if token == self.reset_url_token:
                session_token = self.request.session.get(INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN)
                if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, session_token):
                    # If the token is valid, display the password reset form.
                    self.validlink = True
                    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, token):
                    # Store the token in the session and redirect to the
                    # password reset form at a URL without the token. That
                    # avoids the possibility of leaking the token in the
                    # HTTP Referer header.
                    self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN] = token
                    redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(token, self.reset_url_token)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

        # Display the "Password reset unsuccessful" page.
        if self.validlink:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
        else:
            return redirect("invalid_link_url")
```

The function works but my token is changed when I open the URL.

From `http://localhost:8000/reset/xxx/aj3w7r-8445df53461aeb74dfde3e06357bb6cf/` to `http://localhost:8000/reset/xxx/set-password` when I open.

Note: the `self.reset_url_token`'s value is `set-password`. If I do:
`self.reset_url_token = token`, the page wont load. No error message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. It turned out that this was happening because I was reusing the same p/w reset link (inclusive of the one-time use token) more than once.

If you look at this block (and [this line from the original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a24fed399ced6be2e9dce4cf28db00c3ee21a21c/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L284)), you'll see that the request is redirected to the same path, having set the token value in the request.session, for the reasons that are indicated in the code comment.

```
else:
    if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, token):
        # Store the token in the session and redirect to the
        # password reset form at a URL without the token. That
        # avoids the possibility of leaking the token in the
        # HTTP Referer header.
        self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN] = token
        redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(token, self.reset_url_token)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Ultimately, this dispatch method runs twice, the first time setting the token in the request.session, and the second time running the code block after `if token == self.reset_url_token`.

I'm assuming you're running into this while doing local development. The solution is to go through the reset password flow, as you'll need to trigger a unique token each time.